# uplode image to amazon s3 using @aws-sdk/client-s3 ang get its location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

i am trying upload an in image file to s3 but get this error says :

```
ERROR: MethodNotAllowed: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
```

my code using @aws-sdk/client-s3 package to upload wth this code :

```
const s3 = new S3({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
    }
});

exports.uploadFile = async options => {
    options.internalPath = options.internalPath || (`${config.s3.internalPath + options.moduleName}/`);
    options.ACL = options.ACL || 'public-read';

    logger.info(`Uploading [${options.path}]`);
    const params = {
        Bucket: config.s3.bucket,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(options.path),
        Key: options.internalPath + options.fileName,
        ACL: options.ACL
    };

    try {
        const s3Response = await s3.completeMultipartUpload(params);
        if (s3Response) {
            logger.info(`Done uploading, uploaded to: ${s3Response.Location}`);
            return { url: s3Response.Location };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err, 'unable to upload:');
        throw err;
    }
};
```

I am not sure what this error mean and once the file is uploaded I need to get his location in s3

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seems like they give "Location" in the response anymore.

```
{
'$metadata': {
  httpStatusCode: 200,
  requestId: '',
  extendedRequestId: '',
  cfId: ,
  attempts: 1,
  totalRetryDelay: 0
},
ETag: '',
ServerSideEncryption: ''
}
```

This is the response object.

Use this to get the Location

```
`https://${BUCKETNAME}.s3.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${KEY}`
```

Be sure **"ACL"** is **"public-read"**

Answer (score 2):

For uploading a single image file you need to be calling `s3.upload()` not `s3.completeMultipartUpload()`.

If you had very large files and wanted to upload then in multiple parts, the workflow would look like:

```
s3.createMultipartUpload()
s3.uploadPart()
s3.uploadPart()
...
s3.completeMultipartUpload()
```

---

Looking at the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album-full.html), It looks like the new way to do a simple S3 upload in the JavaScript SDK is this:

```
s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
```

Comment: i see, when i try it it says :
"TypeError: s3.upload is not a function"

am I missing something ?

Comment: Here's the link to the documentation of the `upload()` function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Comment: using `aws-sdk` package it works, but with this package `@aws-sdk/client-s3` it doesn't have the upload function

Comment: @spinker See my updated answer

Comment: i see and it works, the only problem now is that I am not getting the `response.Location` as I used to have when I worked with `aws-sdk` package

Comment: I would start by logging the entire response, I think the location would be in the response.